# Big spaces between items in GridView (WinRT)

Tags: gridview, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

### What i want in the end

a table of items with same appearance (nice controls), but different text on it
smth like this, but much more:

`_ 3  6`
`1  4  7`
`2  5  8`
`_ _ 9`

where "_" is nothing.

### What i have

i have a very simple example with borders in gridView
and i don't understand why is there any spaces between items in GridView.ItemTemplate?
all is ok (i can see full size of border) if i set a bigger value in ItemHeight & ItemWidth
but i this case i have even bigger spaces between items 
`<VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0" ItemHeight="`**I'm about it**`" ItemWidth="`**And it**`" />`

the full code of my example

---

```cs
class SomeData
{
    public SomeData(int i)
    {
        Number = i;
    }

    public int Number { get; set; }
}

class SomeModel
{
    public SomeModel(int key)
    {
        Key = key.ToString();
        Items = new List<SomeData>();
    }

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public List<SomeData> Items { get; set; }
}

class ItemPanelVM : BindableBase
{
    public ItemPanelVM()
    {
        var list = new List<SomeModel>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new SomeModel(i));

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                list[i].Items.Add(new SomeData(j));
            }
        }

        SomeGroup = list;
    }


    private List<SomeModel> _someModels;
    public List<SomeModel> SomeGroup
    {
        get { return _someModels; }
        set
        {
            _someModels = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

---

and xaml snippet

---

```cs
<UserControl.Resources>

    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Key="simpleViewSource"
        IsSourceGrouped="True"
        Source="{Binding SomeGroup}"
        ItemsPath="Items"
        d:Source="{Binding SomeGroup, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=test:ItemPanelVM, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid DataContext="{Binding}">  
    <GridView SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="False" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource simpleViewSource}}" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Margin="0">

        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0" >
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0"
                                               ItemHeight="30" ItemWidth="30" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Border DataContext="{Binding}" Margin="0" Background="Pink" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Brown" Height="30" Width="30">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

---

### Result

### [screenshot](http://sdrv.ms/12STs4X)

### Question

Why? Where are these spaces from?
It's not about i don't know what to do. It's about i don't know what is happening.

P.S. all complaints to google translate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's buried in the depths of the `ItemContainerStyle`; create a copy:

[image]

Then search for the following two elements in the style

```
 <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,2,2"/>
  ...

      <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="4">
```

Set the Margins of both to zero and you'll get the spaces removed. I did note there are a LOT of elements in the style with a hardcoded Margin of 4, so you may need to adjust those too, since some of those elements come into play during various visual states.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just try it and it works. I also deleted a lot of staff like containers about 5 levels nesting and many items for interactivity.